# Tor Functor Commutes with Direct Limits

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> Could somebody please provide a sketch of a proof of the fact that the Tor functor commutes with direct limits?

I have been trying to show that the Tor of a module with the direct limit of a family of modules satisfies the required universal property, but it seems too complex.

Comment: @Manos: $- \otimes N$ commutes with all colimits since it has a right adjoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** Take a short exact sequence $0\to K\to F\to N\to 0$, where $F$ is projective (or free). Then use the long exact homology sequence for Tor and induction on $n$.

Comment: How does this hint connect with what i am trying to prove? What am i inducting on?

Comment: Well, as you know Tor is zero on free modules. Furthermore, Tor has an index and this is the object to induct on.

Comment: Ok, but how does this relate to the directed system of modules and their limit?

Comment: This hint reduces the problem from Tor to $\otimes$. On the way you have to use that the direct limits preserve short exact sequences. Actually the key step is $n=1$ and in this case you have a $3\times 3$ diagram with two vertical isomorphisms, so the third one is isomorphism, too.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean...here is an attempt to understand what you mean: if $\left\{M_i,f_i^j\right\}$ is my directed system of modules, then i can consider an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow K_i \rightarrow F_i \rightarrow M_i \rightarrow 0$ where $F_i$ is free. This gives the long exact sequence $\cdots \rightarrow Tor_1(K_i,N) \rightarrow Tor_1(F_i,N) \rightarrow Tor_1(M_i,N) \rightarrow K_i \otimes N \rightarrow F_i \otimes N \rightarrow M_i \otimes N \rightarrow 0$. Then?

Comment: First of all $Tor_1(F_i,N)=0$. Take the direct limit of what you got and then take the direct limit of the short exact sequences and use again the long exact sequence for Tor for the sequence of direct limits.

Comment: Nice!! And for the $n$-step it turns out that $Tor_{n+1}(M_i,N) \cong Tor_n(K_i,N)$, right?

Answer (score 8):

What is true is that $\rm Tor$ commutes with *filtered* colimits. We already know that $M\otimes -$ commutes with colimits, now take a right $R$-module $M$ and a system $(N_i,\psi_{ji})$ of left $R$-modules over some filtered set $I$. First, we can obtain a short exact sequence of filtered systems

$$0\to (K_i,\rho_{ji})\to (P_i,\tilde\psi_{ji})\to (N_i,\psi_{ji})\to 0$$

by covering $N_i$ by $P_i=R^{(N_i)}$ by $e_n\to n$ and defining $\tilde \psi_{ji}(e_n)=e_{\psi_{ji}n}$, the condition $\psi_{kj}\psi_{ji}=\psi_{ki}$ is immediately inherited by the $\tilde \psi_{ji}$, similarly for the induced morphisms $\rho_{ji}:K_i\to K_j$. Since $I$ is filtered, $\rm colim$ is exact giving an exact sequence

$$0\to {\rm colim}\; K_i \to {\rm colim}\; P_i \to {\rm colim}\;N_i\to 0$$

Call the terms $K,P,N$ for brevity. Since each $P_i$ is flat and $I$ is filtered, $P$ is flat. We may then use the long exact sequence for $\rm Tor$ and obtain a diagram 
$\require{AMScd}$
$$\begin{CD}
  \\
{\rm Tor_1}\;(M,P) @>>>
{\rm Tor_1}\;(M,N) @>>>
M\otimes K  @>>>
M\otimes P
    \\
{}&{}& {} &{}& @VVV @VVV
  \\
{\rm colim}\;{\rm Tor_1}\;(M,P_i)@>>>
 {\rm colim}\;{\rm Tor_1}\;(M,N_i)@>>>
 {\rm colim}\; M\otimes K_i@>>>
{\rm colim}\; M\otimes P_i'  \\
\end{CD}$$

The first two columns vanish since $P_i,P$ are flat, and the last two columns are connected by natural isomorphisms that give a commutative diagram. You can check that if you have an incomplete  commutative diagram with exact rows
$$\begin{CD}
  \\
0@>>>
A  @>>>
B  @>>> 
C    \\
{}&{}& {} &{}& @VVV @VVV
  \\
0 @>>>
A'
  @>>>
B'  @>>>
C'  \\
\end{CD}$$

you may always complete it, and the morphism introduced is an isomorphism if both vertical arrows are. This gives the isomorphism for $n=1$. The case $n\geqslant 1$ is handled by dimension shifting. Indeed, we get a diagram 
$$\begin{CD}
  \\
0@>>>
{\rm Tor}_2(M,{\rm colim}\;N_i)  @>\partial >>
 {\rm Tor}_1(M,{\rm colim}\;K_i)  @>>> 
0    \\
{}&{}& {} &{}& @VVV 
  \\
0 @>>>
{\rm colim}\;{\rm Tor}_2(M,N_i)  @>\partial >>
 {\rm colim}\;{\rm Tor}_1(M,K_i)  @>>> 
0 \\
\end{CD}$$

and we get the desired isomorphism by conjugating the vertical isomorphism. One may show the isomorphism induced is natural, much like that of $M\otimes {\rm colim}$ and ${\rm colim}\; M\otimes $, but that is a bit more tortuous. Note this gives naturality of all the upper isomorphisms, since they are obtained by composing the natural connection morphisms and the natural isomorphism in the case $n=1$.

Comment: Classically, "direct limit" means "colimit of a directed diagram". In particular, they are filtered colimits.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, I agree. However, I have found some books that talk about "directed systems over directed sets" (so "directed systems" are just diagrams over say preorders), hence I think there's no harm in clarifying.