# Union "commutes" with the tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question is related to an exercise in Dummit & Foote's Algebra that establishes a condition for a module to be flat in terms of injectivity of certain maps. There are several questions on this site that deal with this question, eg. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761671/for-every-finitely-generated-ideal-i-subset-a-the-map-i-otimes-a-m-rightarrow).

My question is this:

Suppose $I \subset R$ is an ideal of the commutative ring $R$, and for each finitely generated subideal $J_s \subset I$ you have a map (induced by the inclusion $J_s\subset R$), $\phi_s: M\otimes J_s \rightarrow M\otimes R$. It is known that $I$ is the union of its finitely generated subideals $I = \cup J_s$. Why does it follow that a map $\phi: M \otimes \cup J_s \rightarrow M \otimes R$ exists? Secondly, how does injectivity of this map follow from injectivity of the smaller maps $\phi_s$?

**Note:** the questions on this site deal with this by saying that "the direct limit is an exact functor which commutes with tensor products". In this question **I am looking for a pedagogical answer that avoids concepts from category theory**, i.e. doesn't involve limits, etc.

Comment: For *any* ideal $I\subseteq R$, there is a map $M\otimes I\rightarrow M\otimes R$ induced by the inclusion $I\subseteq R$.

Comment: @Thorgott this much I can believe, but I don't see how a family of such induced maps gives me an injection out of $M \otimes \cup I$.

Comment: Make and combine the observations that a) if $J\subseteq I\subseteq R$ are two ideals in $R$, there are maps $M\otimes J\rightarrow M\otimes I$ and $M\otimes I\rightarrow M\otimes R$ induced by inclusion whose composite is the map $M\otimes J\rightarrow M\otimes R$ induced by inclusion (this is what's known as functoriality) and b) every element of $M\otimes I$ is in the image of $M\otimes J\rightarrow M\otimes I$ for some finitely generated $J\subseteq I$.

Comment: @Thorgott I'm confused about your statement b). You have an inclusion $J \subset I$ but you're claiming every element of $M \otimes I$ is contained in the image of the map induced by the inclusion $M \otimes J \rightarrow M \otimes I$?

Comment: The emphasis is on *for some* $J$. I'm not saying  $M\otimes I$ is the image of some $M\otimes J$ under such a map for a single $J$, but that it is the union of the images of all $M\otimes J$ under these maps for all finitely generated $J$. This is pretty much the same point as the second paragraph of tomasz' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it *follows* that the map $M\otimes \bigcup_s J_s\to M\otimes R$ exists - this is just immediate: if $\sum_k m_k\otimes i_k=0$ for some $i_k\in I$, then it's easy to see that $\sum_k m_k\otimes i_k=0$ in $M\otimes R$ as well (this is true basically whenever $M\otimes I$ is well-defined).

Injectivity of $\phi_s$ does indeed follow from the injectivity of $\phi_s$: briefly, for any $\sum_k m_k\otimes i_k\neq \sum_j m'_j\otimes i'_j\in M\otimes I$, there is some $J_s$ such that all $i_k,i'_j\in J_s$, and the conclusion easily follows by considering $\phi_s$.

Comment: Re: your 1st point: You are saying that the map whose existence I asked about is just the canonical inclusion, as each elementary tensor on the left is contained in the product on the right. Ok, I'm fine with this. My concern is that I'd like "explicitly" construct this canonical inclusion in terms of the $\phi_s$'s I defined. To put it another way, I think it would be fair to say that I'm confused as to what is to be proved here. If we're to use the injectivity of the small maps, then surely the large map should be constructed in terms of the smaller ones. I'd like to see this construction.

Comment: All this easily follows from the [standard construction of the tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#As_a_quotient_space).

Comment: I think I now have a better understanding of what is going on. It is just that the canonical inclusion of a subideal $J$ into $R$ is just the restriction of the canonical inclusion $I \subset R$, and then it follows that tensoring with the identity of $M$ will give a map such $1 \otimes i_I$ which acts on $M \otimes J$ just via the map $1 \otimes i_J$ that is induced by $J \subset R$. So this is not even some kind of property of tensor products and unions, but just a triviality about inclusions? Is that what's happening?

Comment: So the injectivity part is the less trivial one, which boils down to two facts 1) elements of the tensor product are finite linear combinations 2) ideals are unions of finitely generated subideals.

Comment: Pretty much, yes, although techinically, you need to check that the inclusion of $J$ into $I$ induces an inclusion of $R\otimes J$ into $R\otimes I$. Regarding the second part, that's right.

Comment: Thank you, @tomasz.