# Tor commutes with direct limits

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

Weibel has shown that the filtered colimit functor 
$$ \varinjlim :(RMod)^I \rightarrow (RMod)$$
where $I$ is a filtered category, is exact. In [corollary 2.6.16, pg 58](https://math.mit.edu/~hrm/18.906/weibel-homological-algebra.pdf) he claims

> Corollarry 2.6.16. If $F:RMod \rightarrow B$, $B$ an abelian category. and $F$ is a left adjoint, then $L_*F(\varinjlim A_i) \simeq \varinjlim L_*F(A)$.

I am struggling to prove this:

> **Problem:** How does one construct a projective resolution of $\varinjlim A_i$ that respects the preojctive resolution of $P_i \rightarrow A_i$?

I thought $\varinjlim P_i$ would be projective, but this turns out to be false as given in comments.

Comment: ${\mathbb Q}=\lim_{\to}{1\over n}{\mathbb Z}$ is not a projective ${\mathbb Z}$-module.

Comment: @peterag then do you know how one deduces 2.6.16?

Comment: [This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97658/left-derived-functors-commute-with-filtered-colimits) might be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps Weibel is being too fast? See also @PedroTamaroff's answer to "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311615/tor-functor-commutes-with-direct-limits": the argument uses that the filtered direct limit of projectives is flat to show that filtered limits and tor commute (Weibel's Cor 2.6.17).

Comment: And though not pertinent for this question, the following are (links to) Weibel's lists of errata for the text: http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Hbook-corrections.html

Comment: @BryanShih It may be a consequence of Exercise 2.4.2 in Weibel, which says that if $U:\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{C}$ is any exact functor, then $U(L_{i}F)\cong L_{i}(UF)$ for all $i$.