# Flatness criteria on noetherian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

I'm in trouble showing

> when $R$ is a noetherian commutative ring with unity, an $R$-module $M$ is flat if $\text{Tor}_1 (M, R/P) =0$ for any prime ideal $P$ of $R$.

First thought was to use localization, but since $M$ is not finitely generated, couldn't do any. Any hint for this?

Comment: Could you give a motivation/reference where this come from?

Comment: First line, in the second passage of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4726.pdf

Comment: What definition of flatness do you use?

Comment: Flat as flat $R$-moudle? Making tensoring (with $M$) as an exact functor is the only definition I know. What I also know is that $M$ is flat (as I said) iff $\text{Tor}_1(M,R/I)=0$ for any finitely generated ideal $I$ of $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sufficient to show $\operatorname{Tor_1}(M,N)=0$ for all finitely generated modules $N$. Since $R$ is noetherian there is a filtration of submodules: $$0=N_0\subset N_1\subset\dots\subset N_n=N$$ with $N_{i+1}/N_i\cong R/P_i$ for prime ideals $P_i$. By induction on the length $n$ we may assume $\operatorname{Tor_1}(M,N_{n-1})=0$. Then by considering the short exact sequence $$0\to N_{n-1}\to N\to R/P_{n-1}\to0$$ we get the long exact Tor sequence: $$\dots\to\underbrace{\operatorname{Tor_1}(M,N_{n-1})}_{=0}\to\operatorname{Tor_1}(M,N)\to \underbrace{\operatorname{Tor_1}(M,R/P_{n-1})}_{=0}\to\dots$$ i.e. $\operatorname{Tor_1}(M,N)=0$.
If we drop the noetherian assumption and replace the primes $P_i$ with just ideals $I_i$ the same proof works for the statement that $M$ is flat iff $\operatorname{Tor_1}(M,R/I)=0$ for all ideals $I$.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! But I dont know why it's sufficient with finitely generated ones. Or maybe it's with that zero criteria of an element n tensor product? I've just come up with this idea.

Comment: This follows for example from the fact that Tor preserves filtered colimits (see e.g. [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BNF) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311615/tor-functor-commutes-with-direct-limits)) and any module is the filtered colimit of its finitely generated submodules. So we get $\operatorname{Tor}_1(M,N)=0$ for all modules $N$.